# Accessing an event's atttributes in AWS Pinpoint Campaign email template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I have an AWS Pinpoint application.

On the web app front-end, I can trigger an event as follows:

```
       await record('my.event', {
         attributes: { color: 'red', size: 'large' },
         immediate: true
       })
```

In Pinpoint, I can create a campaign with an email template to send an email to the user whenever `my.event` is triggered. I'm able to access the endpoint attributes such as `{{User.UserAttributes.GivenName}}` or `{{Attributes.Preferences.Hats}}`.

However, I'm not able to access the event attributes (`color, size`) in the above example in the email template.

Is there a way to do this?

It seems like you can only filter the events to determine whether the campaign email should be sent (e.g., send only if color==='blue').

I suppose that I could temporarily update the endpoint Attributes before triggering the event, but that is not preferred as it requires an additional call.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out ? I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think accepted attribute values must be lists, such as color: ["red"]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).